# Knockout: how to access element inside the subscribe function

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to get to the bound element from inside the subscribe callback. I have been trying to find something that could point me in the right direction but could not find any. Can you let me know how I can accomplish something like the following:

```
var ViewModel = {
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.Id.subscribe(function(newvalue){
        //I want to get the element that the Id is bound to
        //How can I do that?
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is going against the MVVM pattern

Comment: If you want/need access to the HTML element, you're probably doing something a custom binding handler would solve.

Comment: what is your reason for wanting to know the element? how many elements are bound to the observable? there's more than likely a design issue here that you can refactor to avoid what you're trying to do. if you show some more code or create a JS fiddle with the issue, it may help.

Comment: As others have pointed out, the better way of doing it is to use custom binding handler. Trying to access the element in the subscribe callback is an anti-pattern. I already had some code which was making use of manual subscriptions. So I wanted to leverage that instead of creating a new custom binding handler. In the end I ended up creating a new binding handler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind what context "this" would have inside your subscribe method. like such:

Either bind explicitly:

```
 this.property.subscribe(function(newValue) {
                               this.something(newValue);
                       }.bind(this));
```

or you can do this:

```
this.property.subscribe(function(newValue) {
                           this.something(newValue);
                   }, this);
```

Both approaches have the same outcome.

Comment: This answer needs a little more love! Just be sure the "this" you are binding is the name of the element. If creating an javascript object, it would be the name of the parent object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't on that way, but you can get the element on the `change` event:

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: foo, event: { change: helloElement.bind($data, foo, $element) }" />
```

JS:

```
var model = {
    foo: ko.observable(),
    helloElement: function (value, element) {
        console.log("Hi! I have the value " + value() + " and I live in the element: ", element);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6nH3V/).

Comment: Still a anti pattern!

Comment: I also consider this to be an anti pattern and this will not trigger the event if I change the value of Id programmatically. This only works if the value is changed through the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the similar issue and fortunately had help from a brilliant person.

#### Code

```
for (var row in obj){
    if(typeof(obj[row]) == "function") {
        obj[row].subscribe(function(r) {
            return function(newValue) {
                var _fieldName = r;
                console.log(_fieldName, newValue);
                // Do your stuff
            };
        }(row));
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

Subscribe function requires a function and first parameter of this function is the value (New/Old). So Instead of writing an inline function, return a function of same signature, and bind value to this outer function.

Hope it helps.